# how to extract part of content in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to extract part of value of element and assign that as attribute to it.

source:

```
 <www>
      <sss>
             <eee>XML ELEMENT VALUE 
             [part].HTML element value [HTPART]. 
               HTML element value [HTPART2].
             </eee>
     </sss>
 </www>
```

It continues like this.The content in square braces[] may come many times. And there are many extra spaces in the source. I want to remove the extra spaces and display the content like this.

Output req:

```
      <fff>XML ELEMENT VALUE<ggg name="part"/>.HTML element value<ggg name="HTPART"/>.HTML element value<ggg   name="HTPART2"/>. </fff>
```

can any one suggest how to do this. I am new to XSLT.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is XSLT the only tool you can use? Because this would be a lot simpler outside of XSLT.

Comment: yes.. I am using only XSLT and my task will support only XSLT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String processing is not the strong side of XSLT - it is an XML processing language, after all, not a general-purpose language.

Your problem can be solved through recursion, though:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

  <xsl:template match="eee">
    <fff>
      <xsl:call-template name="process">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text()" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </fff>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="process">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="''" />

    <xsl:variable name="head" select="substring-before($text, '[')" />
    <xsl:variable name="tag"  select="substring-before(substring-after($text, '['), ']')" />
    <xsl:variable name="tail" select="substring-after($text, ']')" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$head != '' and $tag != ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="$head" />
        <ggg name="{$tag}" />
        <!-- recursive step: process the remainder of the string -->
        <xsl:call-template name="process">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$tail" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above template outputs, for your input:

```
 <fff>XML ELEMENT VALUE 
 <ggg name="part"/>.HTML element value <ggg name="HTPART"/>. 
   HTML element value <ggg name="HTPART2"/>.
 </fff>
```